# consumable products are not getting reflected in purchase receipt for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

When I purchase a consumable in-app purchase item I am getting an updated response in the receipt token but when I purchase the same item it is not adding that record to the receipt as my item is consumable and it should be purchased multiple times so if anyone faced the same issue then please tell me what kind of settings I need to make so it can work properly.

Also, subscriptions are working completely fine only issues with consumable products.

Comment: Consumable items do not get added to the receipt. It is up to you to track their purchase and consumption.

Comment: but how to verify the purchase from the server side if they did not add to the receipt do you have any idea, please?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Your server can use the server api to get [purchase details](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_history). There is no need for your app to verify consumable in app purchases at time of purchase; the purchase is delivered to your transaction observer. Once you have the purchase transaction in your app you can simply update your server if you want to record a "balance" on the users account.

Comment: hey @Paulw11, you are right I understood it we only need to verify the subscription. thanks i understood and implemented it